# Proof of existence of Sylow p-subgroup

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

I would like to show that if$\ G $ is a finite group of order$\ p_1 p_2 ... p_k $ where$\ p_i $ are distinct primes, then$\ G $ contains a normal Sylow subgroup and is solvable.

I have problem with proving the first part of this (once we prove that there exists such normal Sylow subgroup, we can easily prove by induction that$\ G $ is solvable, using the fact that if$\ N $ is a normal subgroup of$\ G $ such that$\ G/N $ and$\ N $ are solvable, then$\ G $ is solvable).

I know how to prove it for $\ k=2 $ or$\ k=3 $, but I don't have idea how to prove the general case (I didn't manage to do this by induction, also I think that it would require the proving first that$\ G $ is not simple).

I would be grateful for any hints.

Comment: This is a well-known application of Burnside's Transfer Theorem. Assuming that $p_1 < p_2 < \cdots < p_k$, you use that result to show that $G$ has a normal subgroup of order $p_2p_3 \cdots p_k$, and then everything is straightforward by induction. I don't know any other way of proving this result.

Comment: @DerekHolt: Another proof (if I remember right this is the way it was first done by Frobenius) is to use Frobenius' theorem: if $n$ divides $|G|$, then the number of solutions to $x^n = 1$ in $G$ is a multiple of $n$. Using this one can show that for all $1 \leq i \leq k$, the equation $x^{p_i p_{i+1} \cdots p_k} = 1$ has exactly $p_i p_{i+1} \cdots p_k$ solutions in $G$. In particular $x^{p_k} = 1$ has exactly $p_k$ solutions, so there is a unique Sylow $p_k$-subgroup.